# Ubuntu 15.10 Unity white border around windows

Tags: unity, nvidia, xorg, visual-artifacts

I am using 15.10, and out of blue i started getting a whitish border around my window (all the windows i open).
I have nVidia graphics card with a updated driver.
Everything was fine, no changes were made to any X11 or any system file. Rebooted the machine too. any help ?

[image: whitish border on the terminal]

Comment: on 16.04 using nouveau drivers all is well however when I use nvidia drivers installed from Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers -> Nvidia driver version 378.13 sometime upon a fresh boot up I too see same issue of mysterious white boarders surrounding all windows ... other times a fresh boot the issue is not evident ... it comes and goes ... the plot thickens