# White border after resuming Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 16.10

So I am having this weird issue with Ubuntu. When I open my laptop back up and resume Ubuntu, my normal desktop image is replaced by a white image with what looks like different colored pixels are sprinkled all over the white background.

[image: Messed up desktop]

Then the windows and any type of mouse hover actions, it creates almost the same image for its border. I painted the background purple so the border sticks out a little better.

[image]

Before anyone marks this as a duplicate, I have tried the following solutions:

- [Weird pixelated white border. Ubuntu Xenial (16.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887933/weird-pixelated-white-border-ubuntu-xenial-16-04)- I tried installing nvidia-367 and nvidida-375
- [Strange coloured border appearing around windows [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889166/strange-coloured-border-appearing-around-windows)- this one just points back to the first bullets solution.
- [Weird colored stripes around windows - Ubuntu 16.04 [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886905/weird-colored-stripes-around-windows-ubuntu-16-04/889154#889154)- This has the exact same answer as the first on as well
- [Ubuntu 15.10 Unity white border around windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/757404/ubuntu-15-10-unity-white-border-around-windows)- not the same problem

I have also updated everything within the Ubuntu Software and within the command line apt-get.

So those solutions didn't help. Most of them are pretty much the same exact solution and it still doesn't work. The only way I can get them to stop, is to restart the computer. Are there any other suggestions for me to try? I'm still pretty new to Linux. So please explain what everything does.

My processor: Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz × 8

My GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX 980M/PCIe/SSE2

OS Type: 64-bit

Ubuntu Version: 16.10

**Update**

I tried `compiz --replace` and that appeared to work for the window borders but not the desktop. Also it locked up my Terminal and I tried to close it and it locked up my computer.

Comment: What does `When I open my laptop back up and resume Ubuntu` exactly means?

Comment: When I wake the computer up and resume Ubuntu. When I close it, it goes to sleep.

Comment: I literally just started experiencing this exact issue myself today. I made no changes to the software, just happened all of a sudden. I have a Dell XPS 15 9550.

Comment: Same here - exactly the same. It started happening all of the sudden.

Comment: I've used a combination of `unity --replace` and `sudo systemctl restart lightdm` when the former didn't work. Usually I have to go to a virtual terminal to perform the latter. It's not a solution, but most of the time that keeps me from having to do a full reboot.

Comment: @muru That question was asked the same day as mine.

Comment: Sure, and it now has the most detailed answers related to this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had pretty much the same problem as you, and presumably at the same time (around the 20 or 21st - around 7 days ago), i started getting exactly the same artifacts - though not on chrome, just everything else. If my memory serves, this may be because chrome wrote its own window decorations and I do wonder if that has to do with why its not effected the same.

Im running a similar (but not identical) config, 960M gpu, same CPU. What worked for me was similar to the first post you refer to but used the 370 drivers:

[image: nvidia 370]

After `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

I also found reverting to the Nouveau drivers worked.

I dont think its the best solution ever (I dont like pulling drivers from ppa's for my graphics, but it surfices until the nvidia driver is fixed)

Interesting to note that the same set of updates also broke dns for me. The dnsmasq that network manager runs wasnt surviving suspend/resume either (removing that from network manager has solved the issue, but I dont exactly like that as a fix)

Comment: I'm trying this now. I hope it works because it is very annoying to have that white lines block out my other windows and some times the text box that I am typing in.

Comment: So far it is still working great. I just opened my computer from overnight and it isn't doing it.

Answer (score 1):

This thread ([Strange artifacts along window borders after waking computer from sleep mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896221/strange-artifacts-along-window-borders-after-waking-computer-from-sleep-mode)) has been updated to suggest installing nvidia-381. Working great for me so far ...

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](http://$SITEURL$/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](http://$SITEURL$/help/whats-reputation). If not, tailor the answer to this specific question.